# Creating custom triggers in Zapier

Tags: zapier, intercom

So ive setup intercom to textlocal zaps but there is really no way to create a custom zap. For example, I want to trigger a zap when my clients (registered on intercom) make a purchase or have low credits in their wallet. 
Has anyone set custom triggers before?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom triggers by creating your own app using the [Zapier developer platform](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/). The app is then available within your Zapier account to use with zaps.